# "I want to move here (in) San Pedro."

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

> I want to move here San Pedro.

> I want to move here in San Pedro.

Which one is grammatically correct and why?

Comment: Neither one sounds completely correct.  What are you trying to say?

Comment: Are you talking about relocating to live in San Pedro?  If so, you could say, "I want to move here to San Pedro."

Comment: While both *could* be correct, I think that both are *wrong* because they don't mean what you think they mean.  Please add details: *What or who is "San Pedro"?*  Do you mean *move house*?  If so, where do you move *from*?  And Where do you say these words?

Comment: San Pedro is a location. San Pedro clarifies what "here" means. Kind of like how I can say "I, Anna", Anna is referring to the pronoun "I". Likewise, San Pedro is the definition of "here". But I am not sure if adverbs can work like pronouns in this manner. My intuition tells me that they do not.

Comment: I want to move here to San Pedro or I want to live here in San Pedro - either of those will work.

Answer (score 0):

The basic sentence **I want to move here** is fine.

If you want to clarify that "here" means "San Pedro", then it would be written **I want to move here, San Pedro**.  Saying **I want to move here in San Pedro** could mean "I want to move to this specific location within San Pedro" or "I want to move but I want to stay within San Pedro."

Comment: I thought of adding the comma, however, "I want to move here, San Pedro." seems incorrect because I don't think the noun "San Pedro" can serve as an appositive to "here," which is an adverb. Also, in this sentence, it appears as if I am talking to a person named San Pedro. It is not clear that San Pedro describing "here' unless I add a preposition such as "in" or "to"

Comment: I agree in that I would probably not *write* "I want to move here, San Pedro."  But it's perfectly acceptable in spoken English.

Answer (score 0):

> San Pedro is the definition of "here". But I am not sure if adverbs
> can work like pronouns in this manner. My intuition tells me that they
> do not.

That's okay if you use the right punctuation. A distinct pause is needed before "San Pedro".

I want to move here — San Pedro.